# undefined method `__sort_option__' for :ancestry:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, activeadmin

When trying to view a tree in ActiveAdmin, this is throwing error:
`undefined method 'sort_option' for :ancestry:Symbol`

This doesn't work with the combination: Mongoid, mongoid-ancestry and active_admin-sortable_tree
But works fine with ActiveRecord, Ancestry and active_admin-sortable_tree

Sample source code is at: https://github.com/nahankid/community

**Offending code snippet**

> ```
> def order_by(*spec)
>   option(spec) do |options, query|
>     spec.compact.each do |criterion|
>       criterion.__sort_option__.each_pair do |field, direction|
>         add_sort_option(options, field, direction)
>       end
> ```

**Trace (Incomplete)**

```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `__sort_option__' for
> :ancestry:Symbol):
>     1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)   origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/optional.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in order_by'   origin
> (2.1.1) lib/origin/optional.rb:172:in `each'   origin (2.1.1)
> lib/origin/optional.rb:172:in `block in order_by'   origin (2.1.1)
> lib/origin/optional.rb:314:in `block in option'   origin (2.1.1)
> lib/origin/optional.rb:312:in `tap'   origin (2.1.1)
> lib/origin/optional.rb:312:in `option'   origin (2.1.1)
> lib/origin/optional.rb:171:in `order_by'   active_admin-sortable_tree
> (0.2.0) lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:139:in `block (2
> levels) in build_nested_item'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'  
> arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element' 
> arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'   arbre
> (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `ol'  
> active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:138:in `block in
> build_nested_item'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'  
> arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element' 
> arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'   arbre
> (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `li'  
> active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:117:in `build_nested_item'
> active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in
> build_list'   active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:85:in `each'  
> active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:85:in `block in
> build_list'   arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in
> `block in build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'   arbre
> (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `ol'  
> active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:84:in `build_list'  
> active_admin-sortable_tree (0.2.0)
> lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb:23:in `build'   arbre
> (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in
> build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'  
> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/active_admin-2e5e954bc9b1/lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb:139:in
> `block (2 levels) in render_index'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'  
> arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element' 
> arbre (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in
> `with_current_arbre_element'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'   arbre (1.0.3)
> lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'   arbre
> (1.0.3) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'  
> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/active_admin-2e5e954bc9b1/lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb:138:in
> `block in render_index'   ar
```

Comment: Can you please paste here the offending code and the full error trace?

Answer (score 0):

The offender here is active_admin-sortable tree. It is assuming you are using ActiveRecord and does not comply with Mongoid's sorting syntax.

In Mongoid you must specify the direction of the sort, either 1 or -1 for ascending or descending. This is because MongoDB's query syntax has no assumptions for the direction of the sort if no direction is provided, unlike SQL which assumes ascending if none is given.

So when the gem calls `order` here:

https://github.com/zorab47/activeadmin-sortable-tree/blob/0b78ebffb2e4b702bde99c93fb29b6475504fefc/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_sortable.rb#L139

it's not providing a direction. If it were to do so like so:

`item.send(options[:children_method]).order(options[:sorting_attribute] => :asc).each do |c|`

Then it would be compatible with both, at least *only in this case*. I am not sure what other issues there would be with that gem.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I can do to indicate the sort direction for active_admin-sortable-tree to pick it up?

Comment: You might try setting `:sorting_attribute` to a hash with the direction included. The call would become: `sortable(tree: true, sorting_attribute: { :ancestry => :asc }, collapsible: true, start_collapsed: true)`